# Cardinality of the ring $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/I $ , $I$ is the ideal generated by $ (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1) $

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be the ring $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/I $ , Where $I$ is the ideal generated by $ (x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1) $ and $J$ be the ideal generated by $2$ in $R$.

What is the cardinality of $R$ ?

Comment: What does $J$ have to do with anything? Do you mean the cardinality of $R/J$ in stead?

Comment: No sir ,cardinality of R , and yes I don't know what is the role of J here, I think they did it to confuse the students(sometimes they do it) but I checked the answer and it is infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

The natural embedding $\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[x]$ of $\Bbb{Z}$ as a subring of $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ gives rise to the composition
$$\Bbb{Z}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[x]\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{Z}[x]/I.$$
Show that it is injective by proving that $I\cap\Bbb{Z}=\{0\}$.

---

**Original answer:** (Assuming you meant the cardinality of $R/J$)

**HINT:** There are canonical isomorphisms
\begin{eqnarray*}
R/J&=&(\Bbb{Z}[x]/I)/(2\Bbb{Z}[x]/I))\\
&\cong&\Bbb{Z}[x]/(2,(x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1))\\
&\cong&\Bbb{F}_2[x]/((x^2+x+1)(x^3+x+1)).
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: No, $R/J$ is not isomorphic to $\Bbb{F}_2[x]$, and it is not infinite. I have updated my answer to address the actual question.

Comment: Yes; it is not true that $R/J$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}[x]/2\Bbb{Z}[x]$. What makes you think that?

Comment: The quotients $(\Bbb{Z}[x]/I)/(2\Bbb{Z}[x]/I))$ and $\Bbb{Z}[x]/2\Bbb{Z}[x]$ are not the same.

Comment: No they are not. Note that $2\Bbb{Z}[x]/I$ should be read as $2(\Bbb{Z}[x]/I)$, not as $(2\Bbb{Z}[x])/I$. The latter doesn't even make sense because $I$ is not contained in $2\Bbb{Z}[x]$. The statements in your edit are    wrong.

Comment: Thank you @Servaes  for correcting my mistakes and showing me the right path .

Comment: how does the fact $ I\cap\Bbb{Z} = \{0\} $ imply that there is an injection from $ \mathbb{Z} $ into $ \mathbb{Z}[x]/I $ ?

Comment: The ideal $I\cap\Bbb{Z}$ is the kernel of the composition, because $I$ is the kernel of the second map and the first map is injective.

Comment: Will you please tell me why the kernel of the composition is $ I\cap\Bbb{Z} $

Comment: This is so obvious that I do not understand what you expect me to explain. Is it not clear that $I\cap\Bbb{Z}$ is contained in the kernel? Or that every element of the kernel is contained in both $I$ and $\Bbb{Z}$? Or what?

Comment: Yes  this  is so obvious  and  I had no  idea  what was on my mind  then  , thanks  anyway :)